# In async function, how to access parent variable correctly

Tags: javascript

The code below will not display `Hello` in the console. How can I access the `someVariable` in the async function correcly?

```
var someVariable = 'Hello';
$.get('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
  console.log(someVariable); // Want it to be 'Hello', but it's not.
});
someVariable = '';
```

This is ES5 code. If not simple to fix with ES5, maybe ES6 can help somehow?

Note, the example is not real life code, it is just an example to highlight the problem. In real life, I cannot remove the last line.

Comment: You have manipulated using statement `someVariable = '';` so what do you expect?

Comment: someVariable = ''; gets executed before logging in console

Comment: I know the reason why it does not work, I am wondering how to fix it. And unfortunately I cannot just delete the line that changes the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you say "you don't remove variable change" then everything you can do it's copying data. It may be done in more elegant way through additional self-invoked function:

```
var someVariable = 'Hello';
(function (copiedData) {
    $.get('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
      console.log(copiedData); // Want it to be 'Hello', but it's not.
    });
})(someVariable);
someVariable = '';
```

But be careful: this works only for primitive types and complete reassigning objects but don't work for changes inside objects(or array since they are also objects). For them you will need clone them explicitly

Comment: root cause is: closure is made by name rather by value. to complete demostration you may use `delete someVariable;` instead of assignment and everything works(so callback makes closure to the data `someVariable` is aimed to and regardless variable name is deleted data is still bound to callback code)

Answer (score 3):

No you can't since you are reassigning the variable again later. One possibility is you can make a copy of it before assigning.

```
var someVariable = 'Hello';
$.get('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
  console.log(temp); // Want it to be 'Hello', but it's not.
});
var temp = someVariable;
someVariable = '';
```

For objects, you have to clone unlike primitives.

Comment: it also can be done in slightly more clear way through self-invoked function: `(function (copiedData) {
    $.get('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
      console.log(copiedData); // Want it to be 'Hello', but it's not.
    });
})(someVariable);`

Comment: @ꜱᴜʀᴇꜱʜ ᴀᴛᴛᴀ, nice solution, but this would probably not work in a loop setting, I guess? Ok temp could be an array, but then how to keep track of the index?

Comment: @skyboyer This would also work in a loop situation, would it not? I think it deserves to be an answer and not only a comment...

Comment: @EricC yes, makes sense. Undeleted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility would be to use a promise. Although Suresh has a really simple solution.

```
let someVariable = 'Hello';

let myFirstPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
 $.get('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
    resolve(console.log(someVariable));
  });
});

myFirstPromise.then((successMessage) => {
  console.log(someVariable = '');
});
```